# Select and Update data from the same table in the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a sending email function in my website. I want to have an automatic sending of email  fetched from the database based on the query if EmailSentDate

```
function EmailNotif() {

$stats = 'Open';
$messages = array();

$conn = dbConnect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM invalid_invoice 
            WHERE EmailSentDate<NOW() AND Status=:stats");
$stmt->bindParam(':stats', $stats);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //var_dump($data);

foreach ($data as $row6) {

            $invnumb=$row6['Invoice_Number'];
            $partnumb=$row6['Part_Number'];                                                                                                                                     
            $issue=$row6['Issues'];
            $pic=$row6['PIC_Comments'];
            $issuetype=$row6['Issue_Type'];
            $createdate=$row6['Creation_Date'];
            $site=$row6['Site'];
            $vendor=$row6['Vendor_Name'];
            $invdate=$row6['Invoice_Date'];
            $po=$row6['PO'];
            $rr=$row6['RR'];
            $currency=$row6['Currency'];
            $invamount=$row6['Invoice_Amount'];
            $stat=$row6['Status'];
            $emailadd=$row6['PersoninCharge'];
            $emailid=$row6['ID'];



                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Issue Type: {$issuetype} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Creation Date: {$createdate} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Site: {$site} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Vendor Name: {$vendor} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Invoice Date: {$invdate} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Invoice Number: {$invnumb} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Part Number:</b><br>{$partnumb}<br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>PO: {$po} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>RR: {$rr} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Currency: {$currency} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Invoice Amount: {$invamount} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Issues:{$issue}</b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>Status: {$stat} </b><br><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<b>PIC Comments: {$pic}</b><br>";
                $messages[$emailadd] .= "<br><br>";

}


foreach($messages as $email=>$message) {
    dbInsertEmailMessage($email, "Invalid Invoice Tracking Message", "<html>{$message}</html>");
}

$conn = null;

}

function dbInsertEmailMessage($send_to, $subject, $message) {

        $sql7 = "INSERT INTO email_queue (send_to, subject, message) 
            VALUES (:send_to, :subject, :message)"; 
        $conn = dbConnect();
        $stmt7 = $conn->prepare($sql7); 
        $stmt7->bindParam(':send_to', $send_to);
        $stmt7->bindParam(':subject', $subject);
        $stmt7->bindParam(':message', $message);
        $stmt7->execute();
        $conn=null; 
}
```

I made a query to update the EmailSentDate to todays date but it's not updating. Where should I insert this query? or is there any way I can make it work? Please help. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I added this below code after the function dbInsertEmailMessage. but it's not updating the EmailSentDate to current date.

```
    foreach($emailid as $e_id) {

    $sql2="UPDATE invalid_invoice SET EmailSentDate=:now WHERE ID =:emailid";

    $conn=dbConnect();
    $stmt2=$conn->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':emailid', $e_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':now', $now);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $conn = null;
    var_dump($e_id);

    }
```

Comment: you should execute update query when mail has been successfully sent..`if(mail){update}`

Comment: thanks but it didn't work

Comment: What didn't work about it? Error msgs etc

Comment: It didn't update the EmailSentDate to current date. No error message.

Comment: You should rather use `"UPDATE invalid_invoice SET EmailSentDate=now() WHERE ID =:emailid"` and the no need to bind parameter. currently what is `$now`?